# Função membro independente em C++

Tags: c++, orientação-a-objetos

tô aprendendo POO com C++. Fiz um programa aqui pra treinar questão de arrays de objetos. 
A minha dúvida eh: O programa está funcionando, porém foi eficiente eu ter colocado a função mostrar_dados2 como independente? Não consegui desenvolver a lógica pra colocar ela como uma função-membro da classe pessoa deixando os atributos como privado, pois a função lida com mais de um objeto.

EDIT:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
using namespace std;
#define TAMPESSOAS 4

class pessoa
{
private:
    string nome,signo;
    int idade;
public:
    void mostra_dados();
    void pega_dados();
};

void mostra_dados2(pessoa *pessoas, int cont)
{
    int cont2;

    for (cont2 = 0; cont2 < cont; cont2++)
        pessoas[cont2].mostra_dados();
}

int main()
{
    pessoa pessoas[TAMPESSOAS];//Declaração de um vetor do tipo pessoa
    int cont=0;
    char continuar;
    cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
    cin >> continuar;
    while (continuar == '1')
    {
        pessoas[cont].pega_dados();
        cont++;
        cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
        cin >> continuar;
    }
    mostra_dados2(pessoas, cont);
#if WIN32//Só será executado se o SO for windows
    system("PAUSE");
#endif
return 0;
}
void pessoa::pega_dados()
{
    cout << "\nNome: ";
    cin >> nome;
    cout << "\nSigno: ";
    cin >> signo;
    cout << "\nIdade: ";
    cin >> idade;
}
void pessoa::mostra_dados()
{
    cout << "\nNome: " << nome << "\nIdade: " << idade << "\nSigno: " << 
    signo << endl << endl;
}
```

Comment: coloca o código na pergunta para referencia futura.

Answer (score 1):

Lógicamente que não! Você criou uma função pra fazer algo que você poderia ter feito fora dela (que foi usar um loop `for`)

Melhor teria sido:

```
int main()
{
    pessoa pessoas[TAMPESSOAS];//Declaração de um vetor do tipo pessoa
    int cont=0;
    char continuar;
    cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
    cin >> continuar;
    while (continuar == '1')
    {
        pessoas[cont].pega_dados();
        cont++;
        cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
        cin >> continuar;
    }
    for(int i=0; i<cont; i++)
    {
        pessoas[i].mostra_dados();
    }
    mostra_dados2(pessoas, cont);
#if WIN32//Só será executado se o SO for windows
    system("PAUSE");
#endif
return 0;
}
```

Com isso você não só deixou de criar duas funções com o mesmo nome, sendo uma delas global e que necessita de passar ponteiros e dados por cópia, mas também pode declarar seu metódo como `const` (`void mostra_dados() const;`) o que assegura que nenhum variavel da sua classe tera seu valor modificado durante a execução deste metódo.

Answer (score 1):

Eu acredito que um programa deva ser super fácil de ser lido por um humano, por isso, dividindo o seu programa em funções, cujos nomes mostram qual operação está sendo realizada, facilita a leitura e compreensão do mesmo. Por isso, **sim**, o jeito correto é esse mesmo.

Um array é diferente do que um elemento. Um array lida com a coleção e o elemento lida com um valor em particular. Sendo assim, a função `mostra_dados()` tem como objetivo mostrar, ou formatar, os dados pertinentes à classe `pessoa`, enquanto `mostra_dados2()` tem o objetivo de mostrar os dados das coleção e usa `mostra_dados()` para formatar o particular. Talvez o nome `mostra_dados2()` é que não foi muito feliz (talvez `imprimir`, possa ser um nome melhor).

Com relação ao seu programa, C++, na verdade, o STL, tem vários objetos que facilitam e aumentam a robustez de seu programa. Um deles é o `vector`. O STL também tem vários algoritmos para facilitar a navegação destes objetos, um deles é o `for_each`. Por fim, um das característica do C++ é a capacidade de `overload`. Você pode substituir a função `mostra_dados()` por um `overload` do operador<<.

Assim, o seu programa pode ser reescrito da seguinte forma:

```
#include"stdafx.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;
#define TAMPESSOAS 4

class pessoa
{
private:
    string nome,signo;
    int idade;
public:
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const pessoa &p);
    void pega_dados();
};

template <typename T>
void imprimir(const std::vector<T> &o)
{
    std::for_each(o.begin(), o.end(), [](const T &p){std::cout << p;});
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<pessoa> pessoas;//Declaração de um vetor do tipo pessoa
    pessoas.reserve(TAMPESSOAS);

    char continuar;
    cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
    cin >> continuar;
    while (continuar == '1')
    {
        pessoa p;
        p.pega_dados();
        pessoas.emplace_back(p);
        cout << "\nContinuar a pegar dados? 1 para sim: ";
        cin >> continuar;
    }
    imprimir(pessoas);
#if WIN32//Só será executado se o SO for windows
    system("PAUSE");
#endif
    return 0;
}
void pessoa::pega_dados()
{
    cout << "\nNome: ";
    cin >> nome;
    cout << "\nSigno: ";
    cin >> signo;
    cout << "\nIdade: ";
    cin >> idade;
}

std::ostream& operator<<(ostream& o, const pessoa &p)
{
    cout << "\nNome: " << p.nome << "\nIdade: " << p.idade << "\nSigno: "     << 
    p.signo << endl << endl;
}
```